# Deployed Outlook addin not loaded

Tags: outlook, add-in

I cannot get my Outlook addin to work in release mode for OL2007 (debug works great). I created a ClickOnce installer, signed it with a custom certificate and built the installer.

Then after installation when I start Outlook 2007, it does not load and gives no notification at all. I look into the addin section where I find my addin among "inactive addins". I look to the COM addins and find it unchecked (checking it doesn't help) with the notification "Not loaded" (NOTHING ELSE).

Things I tried already:

1. try/catch block around my startup routine plus message output: nothing is shown
2. new custom signing certificate: useless
3. APPDATA\MS\Outlook\extend.dat deleted: to no avail
4. regedit setting "LoadBehaviour" 3: It is always like that, I don't have to change it
5. VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS = 0: to no avail, nothing is shown
6. VSTO_LOGALERTS = 1: same here, nothing is logged
7. Fusion Logging: nothing is posted into the output directory

I get NO info at all what causes my addin not to load. It is driving me crazy. Can anyone point me to a solution or at least something I can still try to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem obviously occurred due to a difference between GUID and setup product key. Changing the setup product key to match the GUID enabled the addin to complain about errors again, so I could continue with debugging.

Very weird that in this case no error whatsoever was thrown.